# Estimating and using reliability metric with the same data

Tags: reliability, psychometrics, measurement

I'd like to know if it is reasonable to use the same set of data to estimate and use a reliability metric from repeated measures? I am mostly interesting by the minimal detectable change (MDC). But I thought that the MDC was a property of a measuring instrument BEFORE using that instrument. Is that wrong?

Is it cheating to estimate the MDC and then use it to determine if a change has really happened?